# Does Amazon Glue Supports On Premises DB as Source in a secure manner

Tags: amazon-web-services

Trying to understand the possibility of using Amazon Glue with On Premises DB. 
As per the following [amazon reference document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-connections.html?icmpid=docs_glue_console)  we can use JDBC But this DB is behind firewall and in organization network so publicly not accessible. So What is the best way to connect to an On-Premises DB from Amazon Glue.

Answer (score 1):

Good Day,

Glue is able to setup the connection on to your on premise Oracle and SQL Server Databases via the JDBC protocol.

All you have to ensure is that your firewall on premise allows access from AWS Glue.

You make also have to create a VPN Access in to your local network then you are able to work with your Glue.

AWS Glue can connect to the following data stores by using the JDBC protocol:

- Amazon Redshift
- Amazon Relational Database Service

  ```
  ○ Amazon Aurora
  ○ MariaDB
  ○ Microsoft SQL Server
  ○ MySQL
  ○ Oracle
  ○ PostgreSQL
  ```
- Publicly accessible databases

  ```
  ○ Amazon Aurora
  ○ MariaDB
  ○ Microsoft SQL Server
  ○ MySQL
  ○ Oracle
  ○ PostgreSQL
  ```

[Reference link 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-add-connection.html#connection-JDBC-VPC)

[Reference link 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-connections.html)

[Reference link 3](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=264897)

Trust you find this helpful.

Comment: I found [a post](https://www.accenture.com/us-en/blogs/blogs-kalyani-sayyed-amazon-glue-etl) mentioned that `AWS Glue does not directly support crawlers in on-premises data sources.`, not sure if that is truth.

Comment: I can connect my onprem db from Glue catelog, but how do you deal with SSL connection ?